# GetAllUsers issue, ignore subordinated OUs

Tags: c#, active-directory

Im trying to make an Active-Directory Management tool for my company and i want to get all Users from a specific OU, without getting Results of the under(?)-OU.

The structure is like this:

```
->XXXX.de

-->Germany

--->Users (Here are the Users i want to get)

(These are the unnecessary OUs / Results)

----> Administrative accounts

----> Other Accounts
```

My LDAP-Link (ldapPath) for the DirectorySearcher is

```
"LDAP://OU=Users,OU=Germany,DC=XXXX,DC=de".
```

Code:

```
public SearchResultCollection getAllUsers(string location)
{
    string ldapPath;

    SearchResultCollection allResults;

    try {

        ldapPath = getLdapPathFromLocation(location);

        DirectoryEntry entry = createDirectoryEntry(AD_BWFE, ldapPath);

        DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAmAccountName");

        allResults = searcher.FindAll();

        return allResults;
    }
```

Comment: So which error does happen?

Comment: I dont get any Error, i just get many unnecessary Results, thats my Problem

Comment: The most common usage, the most useful one, is a recursive search. That is the reason it is the default behaviour. Check damien's answer to know how to alter it.

Comment: Can you use searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.OneLevel; ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure the [`DirectorySearcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.searchroot?view=netframework-4.7.2) so that it's searching specifically in the `Users` OU and then specify the [`SearchScope`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.searchscope?view=netframework-4.7.2) property as `SearchScope.OneLevel` (the default is `SubTree`).

Unfortunately, the only constructor overload that allows you to specify both at once is the [kitchen sink constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DirectoryServices_DirectorySearcher__ctor_System_DirectoryServices_DirectoryEntry_System_String_System_String___System_DirectoryServices_SearchScope_).

Comment: Not in a useful constructor, but it is also a a writable property. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.searchscope?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @bradbury9 - that's why the links in the first paragraph are to the properties.